# VBA Selenium - Wait for Iframe to load

Tags: vba, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to log in to a webpage on chrome and wait for the a specific iframe to load, can anyone help me with the code using vba selenium?

```
bot.Start "chrome", ""
bot.Get "weburl"
On Error GoTo a
bot.Wait "2000"
bot.FindElementById("loginUserName").SendKeys Sheets("SUMMARIZE CLP").[b1]
bot.FindElementById("loginPassword").SendKeys Sheets("SUMMARIZE CLP").[b2]
bot.Wait "2000"
bot.FindElementById("loginButton").Click
a:
bot.SwitchToFrame (0)
bot.FindElementById("rpFilterComboBox-1039-inputEl").SendKeys Sheets("CLP FROM OFFICE").[bd1] ' this is where i got error
```

Answer (score 0):

i've just found the answer:

Looks like im just gonna wait until the element in that iframe exist:

```
bot.SwitchToFrame (0)
On Error Resume Next
Do While IsError(bot.FindElementById("rpFilterComboBox-1039-inputEl")) = True
Loop
bot.FindElementById("rpFilterComboBox-1039-inputEl").SendKeys Sheets("CLP FROM OFFICE").[bd1]
bot.FindElementByXPath(".//*[text()=' in Wave'] ").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine your Selenium Driver is a copy of Internet Explorer. Then do this.

```
Do While bot.FindElementById("rpFilterComboBox-1039-inputEl").IsDisplayed = False
    DoEvents
Loop
```

While you wait until your element appears, your VBA host will have control. I prefer this solution, because it doesn't break error handling when you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Set and implicit wait

Bot.timeouts.implicitwait = 20000

Time is in ms, then it will wait up to that amount of time, if the code skips the element because it found it and its value is nothing, you could use an if statement

Checkagain:
Bot.wait 1000
If bot.findelementbywhatever("your element").text = "" then
Goto checkagain
Else
End if